# What could be causing traceroute to only show gateway and final destination?

Tags: networking, traceroute

I am expecting trace route to show pings all along the route like as on my computer (as is often true, there are a few "Request timed out"). THis is meant to demonstrate the problem its not about the destination IP in the example. We both tracerouted to this random IP far away:

```
$traceroute 211.220.0.194

Tracing route to 211.220.0.194 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  <REMOVED>
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  <REMOVED>
  3    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  <REMOVED>
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6   226 ms   226 ms   226 ms  112.174.87.85
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
.
etc.........
```

But my friend has Google Nest wifi and he gets only reply from his gateway and end destination:

```
$traceroute 211.220.0.194
Tracing route to 211.220.0.194 over a maximum of 30 hops
  1     2 ms     1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.2.1
  2     3 ms     3 ms     3 ms  211.220.0.194
Trace complete.
```

What could be causing my friend's trace route to behave this way?
This suggests that something very strange is going on with Google Nest. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: what were you expecting to see?

Comment: @jsotola Im expecting to see trace route pings all along the way to the target. See a regular trace route shows you pings all the way along the route? And my friend is only seeing the gateway and the end destination.

Comment: is the destination on the same router as the linux pc?

Comment: Guess: Routing happens "below" what you see (if you want, the packets are tunnelled). Quite a few tier 3 ISPs do that in their internal networks.

Comment: @dirkt Thank you, your response is making sense. Might you know how to shut off this tunneling. Google Next tunneling is causing severe lag. I just want to direct friend on how to disable that so that I can connect from his home router to destination servers.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend's Google Nest has the IP Address 211.220.0.194. It's local with respect to your friend, but across the internet from you. The `*`s in the `traceroute` output are systems that don't reply and timeout. Try an IP Address that's remote from you both, e.g. `google.com`: `traceroute 8.8.8.8`.

Comment: Hi that 211.220.0.194 is actually in South Korea. The point was that we both traceroute to the same IP. So dirkt said Google Nest is tunneling the connection and we're not seeing the route pings. (See my results - we both tracerouted to the same distant server. I get pings along the way, he doesnt)